# How to access map values / iterate over map in Polymer.dart 0.5

Tags: dart, polymer

I am working on my first polymer application and I am stuck. How do I access map values with polymer?
I have a class with a map within. I can iterate over lists in my template, but how to get all values from a map?

```
 query('#tmpl-question').model = q;
 query('#tmpl-answers').model = q.map_answers;


@observable
class Question extends PolymerElement with ObservableMixin{

  @observable
  Map<String,String> map_answers = toObservable({}); //new Map<String,String>();

  void initQuestion(){

    map_answers["false1"]="1";
    map_answers["true"]="42";
    map_answers["false2"]="2";}}
```

---

```
        <template id="tmpl-answers" repeat>
        <p>
           <label for"a1" value="asdf"> HOW TO DISPLAY ALL MAP VALUES  //iterate over list elements with {{}}
        </p>
       </template>
```

**EDIT: the problem was with the assignment of the object `q` to the model.**

does not work:

```
Question q = new Question();
   query('#tmpl-question').model = q;
```

if you **import 'package:polymer_expressions/polymer_expressions.dart';** this will work:

```
  TemplateElement template = query('#tmpl-question');
  template.bindingDelegate = new PolymerExpressions(globals: {
    'uppercase': (String input) => input.toUpperCase()
  });
  template.model = q;
```

.

```
 <template repeat="{{j in map2.keys}}">
        <li>{{map2[j]}}</li>
      </template>
```

Comment: For Dart Polymer 1.0 see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20334001

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maps have two iterable properties: `keys` and `values`. I think what you want to do is iterate over the keys and then access the values.

Something like:

```
<polymer-element ... >
  <template>
    <template repeat="{{ key in map_answers.keys }}">
      <p>
        <label>{{ map_answers[key] }}</label>
      </p>
    </template>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: thx! I had the same code but I was missing the PolymerExpressions thing. This is confusing.

Comment: PolymerExpressions is already the default, you shouldn't have needed to set the binding delegate unless you needed to add globals.

Comment: Jessica, which version of Polymer are you using? This question is a little old, so it's referring to the 0.5 version. Iteration is completely different in Polymer 1.0