# What is the alternative to maps in polymer Dart 1.0?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I notice in the [Polymer Dart issue #569](https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/569), that the use of maps is discouraged, because they're inefficient. What is (will be) the alternative? I use maps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The original reasoning for the comment about inefficiency no longer applies. Previously the whole map had to be copied to a new JsObject each time it was passed to JS, but that is no longer the case.

Comment: How do I actually update values in a map, so that Polymer gets notified?

Comment: You can just use the normal `set` and `notifyPath` apis (use map keys as part of the path)